# if else nesting, and using a var toggle to id and change elements

Tags: jquery

I have code that grabs an input field element 'distance', and converts it to miles.

My problem is that it's applying the calc everytime the measurement dropdown is changed. This means the calc is applied for example, to kilometers, when kilometers is already selected. Below I have tried to implement a toggle to overcome this. But there has to be a better way.

```
<script>
    $('select').on('change', function (event) {

    var measurement = $('#measurement').val();
    var distance = $('#distance').val();
    var value = 0;
    var toggle = off;
    if (measurement == "miles")
    {
    value = (distance * 0.62137119);
    toggle = on;
    }
    else if (measurement == "kilometres")
    {
        if (toggle == on)
        {
        value = (distance / 0.62137119);
        toggle == off;
        }
    }
    $("#distance").val(value.toFixed(0))
    }); 
</script>
```

Q: How can I have a dropdown to select Miles/Kilometers, so that my element 'distance' shows correctly?

Note: the element distance is a text input element element populated from a PHP MySQL DB query prior.

HTML

```
<select name="measurement" name="measurement" id="measurement">
<optgroup label="measurement">
<option value="">Please Select Imperial or Metric</option>
<option value="kilometres" selected="selected">kilometres</option>
<option value="miles">miles</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" size="5" id="distance" name="distance" value="10" class="value" />
```

CodeIgniter Module to populate drop down list

```
<?php
class Measurement extends CI_Model
{
    function get_measurement()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('select * from measurement ORDER by name');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $measurementdata[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
            }
            return $measurementdata;
        } else {
            return false; // return false if no items for dropdown
        }
    }
}
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJYw7/14/

Comment: You seem to be saying that the change event fires even when you don't change the value in the dropdown?  That shouldn't be.  Can you recreate this in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Wouldn't moving your first option in the optgroup solve this? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SJYw7/17/

Comment: Yes it's weird. So default to kms set at 1500 kms results in 2414... it's dividing by 0.62.

Comment: @j08691 I added my CodeIgniter Module, that's how the list is populated (from the database).

Comment: "toggle == off" that's completely incorrect.

Comment: I wouldn't have come here if it wasn't:)

Comment: Could it be a conflict with some other javascript on the page?